# google maps not rendering in a nested div

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am using [this][1] tutorial to render google map on my webpage. It works fine when I use it in the way it's in this tutorial. But it doesn't render on my webpage.

I have a tabbed webpage. Each tab content is opened with a div containing its id. So when I put the div with the id of map which is used by render map function to render map, it's inside the div of a Live Map tab. And it's not working.

Here is my code:

**Tabbed HTML on my webpage:**

```
<div class="tab"> //tabs defined
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab1')">tab1</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab2')">tab2</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Live-Map')">Live Map</button>
</div>

<div id="Live-Map" class="tabcontent"> //map div inside tab div
<div id="map"></div>  //map div
</div>

<script> // tab selector js function
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
```

**EDIT**

**CSS**

This is css. Trying solutions from other sources, I found the height of the parent div needs to be made 100%. I did that too but still no success.

```
 #map {
   height: 100%;
 }
#Live-Map {
   height: 100%;
 }
 /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
 html, body {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

I solved the problem with bit search. The problem basically was have to give the wrapper div also 100% height & width and also to the bootstrap container div. Because Google API requires these parameters to render,

```
 #Live-Map, #map {
       height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
     }
   /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
     html, body {
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}

<div style="Height:100%; Width:100%;" class="container-fluid">
```

Answer (score 0):

if the map  is not visible during first presentation the map don't work  .. in this case you could  add the code for initMap direcly in you openCity function

```
    function openCity(evt, cityName) {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(60.378920, 24.741850),
          zoom: 7
        });

    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Comment: This is and other methods are covered in the duplicate question.

Comment: I commented the function in the code and updated openCity with your code but then it started showing error on line         var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow; in browser 'Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined'

Comment: this mean that you some others reference to  the map  object ..  you should rethink you solution starting to the fatc you have not a valid map at startup.. you  must create a valid map objec  in the function that render the page (tab) where there is the map

Comment: I was putting incomplete initMap() function inside openCity(). I put complete now, it's raising this error: Uncaught (in promise) 
Kc
message: "initMap is not a function"
name: "InvalidValueError"  .....................

Comment: You are calling initMap somewhere (could be in you google maps  request) declaration  ..  you should remove the initMap call

Comment: initMap() is called with GoogleAPI key only:
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=goolekey&callback=initMap">
    </script>

Comment: if you  don't show the map at the startup  .. you don't need  this call ..

Comment: But what about GoogleAPI key then ? Because I don't think maps will load without that.

Comment: You need the  google maps  API call  ..just remove &callback=initMap

Comment: I tried that already but nothing happens. no error but no map in 'live map' tab  content.

Comment: I  don't know you code  ,...  if you have an initial map that show the map  then use  the initMap for render  this  inital map  ..  .. but remember that you  you must recreate a valid map  for each hiddend tab when you click for show  ..

Comment: There is no initial map. The code that I put in EDIT is the complete code for Live Map tab. This all code is inside the div for the tabcontent. What I want is when tab is clicked, the map appears.

Comment: The problem basically was have to give the wrapper div also 100% height & width and also to the bootstrap container div. Because Google API requires these parameters to render,      
 #Live-Map, #map {
       height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
     }
   /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
     html, body {
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}

Comment: @scaisEdge: thank you for the nice help :-)

Comment: @XCeptable  you are welcome ..